# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, maven

When trying to load the application context from the SpringJunit4ClassRunner for unit test cases throwing exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailingThreadService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

The code is as follows

```
public class XXXXThreadServiceImpl extends BaseXXXXServiceImpl
    implements XXXXThreadService, Runnable {

    public void initialize() {
    }
}
```

In application context file for spring is as follows

```
<bean id="mailingThreadService" class="com.xd.mailinglist.services.impl.MailingThreadServiceImpl"
        init-method="initialize" destroy-method="shutdown" scope = "singleton">
    <property name="serviceAgent" ref="cassNcoaServiceAgent"/>
    <property name="dao" ref="addressDataService"/> 
</bean>
```

The unit test goes here

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( {"/applicationContext.xml"})
public class SomeServiceImplTest {
}
```

When we install using maven its throwing the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailingThreadService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Post here your console with stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)